# WTForms decimalfield raises type error on getting u'' input

Tags: python, wtforms

I am using WTForms with cherrypy with a decimal field but I'm getting a typeError exception when I pass a u"" string to it.  It says it needs a float when it runs the _value function.  It would be nice for wtforms to respond with its validation error but its excepting.

I'm passing u"" to the decimal field.  It works when a number is in there.  It also works when I don't use a decimal field but use a float field.  Long story short I can pas u"" to a FloatField but not a DecimalField.

Comment: What's your question? Bug reports should go to WTForms' issue tracker, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Because in my experience it's never a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out you have to use werkzueg multidict and pass the kwargs to that for your forms for cherrypy.

http://groups.google.com/group/wtforms/msg/27a20dab9d24ca80